# Convert JavaScript List Button to Lightning

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-experience

I have a js list button which opens up new record (on edit mode) and pre-populate fields.
I'm trying to figure out - what is the best way to convert this button to be lightning ready, but also keep the same functionality.

Creating new lightning component will not be good enough, because this action won't be available as related list button (like the js button).

Also, the new record needs to be open up on edit mode.

I tried the Lightning Experience Configuration Converter, but didn't get any answers.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Spring '20, you can now set a custom button to [Navigate to a Record’s Create Page with Default Field Values](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_general_lex_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm)

You can see this [recent question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/298314/create-custom-url-button-for-case-creation-field-pre-population#comment446514_298314) for an example of someone using it as well as the example provided by the release notes below:

```
/lightning/o/Account/new?defaultFieldValues=
    Name={!URLENCODE(Account.Name)},
    OwnerId={!Account.OwnerId},
    AccountNumber={!Account.AccountNumber},
    NumberOfEmployees=35000,
    CustomCheckbox__c={!IF(Account.SomeCheckbox__c, true, false)}
```